# Rails grouped collection select limit list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `grouped_collection_select` where I would like to limit the records displayed to tasks that are not closed. I can easily filter the records displayed at the opt group of the collection list.  But, I can't filter the option level records (group_method).

This is in my Task model:

```
  scope :tasknotclosed, where("taskstatus_id != (?)", 3)
```

This is the current select:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :task_id, Workorder.wonotclosed.order(:description), :tasks, :description, :id, :taskname, :include_blank => 'Select:' %>
```

Instead of `:tasks`, I would like to use something like `Task.tasknotclosed.all`

But, that gives me:

```
syntax error, unexpected '['
```

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE 1

I tried adding this to the task model:

```
def tasknotclosed?
  self.taskstatus_id != 3
end
```

And changed the select to:

```
<%= grouped_collection_select(:tasks, :task_id, Workorder.wonotclosed.order(:id), :task.tasknotclosed?, :description, :id, :taskname, :include_blank => true) %>
```

But I get:

```
undefined method `tasknotclosed?' for :task:Symbol
```

UPDATE2

I changed the select in the Events form to this:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :task_id, @workorderlist, @tasklist, :description, :id, :taskname, :include_blank => 'Select:' %>
```

And the Events controller to this:

```
 def new
  @event = Event.new
  @tasklist = Task.where("showtimer == (?)", true).order(:taskname)
  @workorderlist = Workorder.where("wostatus_id != (?)", 15).order(:description)
```

The `@workorderlist` works the way I expected.

But, the @tasklist gives me

```
syntax error, unexpected $end
```

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select

there are some quite explanatory examples there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I'm not sure where you are on this after previous comments and answer, but assuming your post above still stands, it looks like you're doing grouped_collection_select wrong. According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select), it should be more like

```
grouped_collection_select :event, :task_id, @workorderlist, @tasklist, :description, :id, :taskname
```

But part of the problem may be using an instance variable (@tasklist) when there should be a method there. The fourth element needs to be a group_method (= "The name of a method which, when called on a member of collection, returns an array of child objects representing the  tags.") You can't call @tasklist on a member of your collection. So I would suggest making this an object method in your work_order model (assuming work_order has_many :tasks), like so:

```
class WorkOrder
  def tasklist
    tasks.where(<conditions>)
  end
end
```

so that then you can actually call the method :tasklist in that fourth position there.

Comment: Absolutely right about the fourth param.  For the question at hand I'd guess that an 'incomplete_task_list' method would make the most sense.  Probably contains something like tasks.where('taskstatus_id != 3').order(:taskname) given the preceding discussion.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it and let you know

Comment: This worked!! ` def incomplete_task_list
    tasks.where("taskstatus_id != (?)", 3).order(:taskname)
  end`

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to generate by your own needed Array with options, it must looks something like -

   `['North America',
    [['United States','US'],'Canada']],
   ['Europe',
    ['Denmark','Germany','France']]`

then use grouped_options_for_select

1. Maybe you can try to use simple_form gem.
2. Code `scope :tasknotclosed, where("taskstatus_id != (?)", 3)` - try to implement it as instance method of class Workorder, e.g. `def tasknotclosed`

Comment: Task.tasknotclosed.all
needs to be a nested array?